# Java/Groovy: Randomize Encryption String Better

Tags: java, encryption, groovy, aes

I use encryption to create query parameters that get emailed to individuals with download links to various files.  However, I've noticed that the encrypted strings are fairly similar for similar file names.  I'd like to change that.

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance('AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding')
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec('****************' as byte[], AES'),
    new IvParameterSpec('***************' as byte[]))
String fileId = Base64.encodeBase64String(
    IOUtils.toByteArray(
        new CipherInputStream(
            new DeflaterInputStream(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(
                    ('File: ' + filename).getBytes('UTF-8')
                )
            ), cipher
        )
    )
)
```

For example if I have a file called Something_8.3.0.1471.exe and Something_8.3.0.1471_License.txt I would get the following two strings:

```
mVjCmP2GCyxMJ1i5GHT1OOZEYXy1%2Buz%2BQ53QMelR4QU%2FTowMdjNcMjojlbjuTJEd
```

and

```
mVjCmP2GCyxMJ1i5GHT1OB%2F5S1rolp%2BwK9dATPdPtHn3uQiXnYUhLmym6hMI65TVfjA5IzSYInI9iIjZn9eExg%3D%3D
```

The first 20 or so characters of the encrypted string are identical, obviously because the beginning of the file names is identical.  I was wondering if it's possible to remove this identicallity (if that's a word).  Is it possible to have any change in the unencrypted string more prominently impact the whole encrypted string?  If so, how would I go about making this change in Java/Groovy in the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same key and same plain text will always produce the same cipher text when used in [deterministic encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_encryption) scheme. [Probabilistic encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_encryption) schemes introduce some randomness factor so that continuous invocations of encryption with the same key and same plain text produce different cipher texts.

Some crypto algorithms (like EC signatures) generate random values internally and do not even expose them to the user as they do not need to store the value of that randomness factor in order to decrypt the cipher text (or validate a signature) but in most ciphers the user is *trusted* to provide a random factor like initialization vector or nonce.

AES has a block size of 16 bytes, meaning that it splits the input into 16-byte chunks and processes each chunk separately (in ECB mode) or mixing in the previous processing results in some way (in most other cipher modes). For the very first block regardless of the cipher mode used the only inputs are the key, the IV and the first 16 bytes of the input.

In your example the first 16 bytes are the same in both cases, and it seems that you use the same key and same IV (one of the greatest crypto sins, by the way). As expected, the first 16 bytes (or, equivalently, first 20 Base64 characters) are the same.
The next 16 bytes of the input are different, which leads to completely different second block of cipher text.

You must not use the same IV value twice. Use `SecureRandom` to generate unique IV values for each encryption attempt.

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
byte bytes[] = new byte[16]; // use the proper IV size for selected cipher
random.nextBytes(bytes);
```

When using a single storage entity (a single file, for example) storing the IV before the cipher text is the de facto standard, but it is not required (you can store the IV and the cipher text in a separate database columns, for example).

You must not use keys created by simply converting a character sequence into a byte sequence. Such keys have predictable properties (for example, for ASCII text your key will never contain bytes in the range of [0..31]). If you need a password-based key then use the proper key derivation function like PBKDF2.